# MySql filter query to product variant table

Tags: mysql, sql, product, variant

I need to filter products by the variants content but I'm completely stuck, the structure is the following:

I have those 3 Tables:

PRODUCT

```
 ______ _________
|  id  |  title  |
|------|---------|
|   1  |  Shirt  |
|   2  |  Hood   |
```

PRODUCT_VARIANT

```
 ______ ___________
|  id  |  product  |
|------|-----------|
|   1  |  1        |
|   2  |  1        |
|   3  |  2        |
```

PRODUCT_VARIANT_CONTENT

```
 ______ ___________ __________ __________
|  id  |  variant  |  option  |  content |
|------|-----------|----------|----------|
|   1  |  1        |   1      | small    |
|   2  |  1        |   2      | blue     |
|   3  |  2        |   1      | small    |
|   4  |  2        |   3      | red      |
|   5  |  3        |   1      | small    |
```

Ok...
So, if I need to get all products that is RED I perform the following query:

```
SELECT
    P.id,
    P.`title`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(PVC.content) AS content
FROM
    product P
LEFT JOIN product_variant PV ON PV.product = P.id
LEFT JOIN product_variant_content PVC ON PVC.variant = PV.id
WHERE PVC.content = 'red'
GROUP BY
    P.id, PV.id
```

It will return:

```
 ______ ___________ _________ 
|  id  |  title  |  content  |
|------|---------|-----------|
|   1  |  Shirt  |  red      |
```

Thats is Ok, the result I was expecting, but I Need to get all products that are Small AND Red at the same time, I don't know how to achieve this, can somebody help me with this?

EDITED!
I Got the solution, if somebody reach this page, the problem was solved using this query:

```
SELECT
    P.id,
    P.`name`,
    PVC1.content,
    PVC2.content
FROM
    product P
JOIN product_variant PV ON PV.product = P.id
JOIN product_variant_content PVC1 ON PVC1.variant = PV.id AND PVC1.content = 'red'
JOIN product_variant_content PVC2 ON PVC2.variant = PV.id AND PVC2.content = 'small'

GROUP BY
    P.id, PV.id
```

Comment: Oh the joys of writing SQL to work with an EAV model...  what would be trivial in a relational model is made an order of magnitude more difficult.

Comment: You can use a separate join path for each content value.  Two joins to PRODUCT_VARIANT_COLUMN, one for 'red' the other for 'small'.  This same question has been asked numerous times on StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269135/mysql-eav-match-row-as-field-or-entitys-property-value  To find other questions about SQL related to the EAV model, include the tag entity-attribute-value in your search.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this be achieved by adding an AND clause to your WHERE statement. As in,

```
WHERE PVC.content = 'red' AND PVC.content = 'small'
```

Comment: You would *think* it would be that simple. But it's not. How many rows, exactly do you think are going to satisfy both conditions.  If the value of the `condition` is equal to 'red'... what's the likelihood that same value is going to be equal to 'small' ?  I give this a about a 0.00% chance of returning a row.

Comment: Well technically, it answered the question, which was poorly worded. It seems the OP actually wanted OR